# "It is good that" vs. "It is well that"

Tags: difference

Why does each of the following quotations use "It is ***well*** that"? Why not "It is good that"?

Walter Scott, [*The Bride of Lammermoor* (1819) /Volume 1/Chapter 6 - Wikisource, the free online library](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Bride_of_Lammermoor/Volume_1/Chapter_6).

> [[173]](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3AScott_-_Tales_of_my_Landlord_-_3rd_series%2C_vol._1_-_1819.djvu/183) "There," said Ravenswood, "sits the only male domestic that remains to the house of Ravenswood; and it is ***well*** that he does remain there, since otherwise, we had little hope to find either light or fire. But follow me cautiously; the road is narrow, and admits only one horse in front."

[*Oxford*, by C. S. Lewis | Poeticous: poems, essays, and short stories](https://www.poeticous.com/c-s-lewis/oxford?filter=likes)

> It is ***well*** that there are palaces of peace
> And discipline and dreaming and desire,
> Lest we forget our heritage and cease
> The Spirit’s work—to hunger and aspire:

*Pearce & Stevens' Trusts and Equitable Obligations* 7 edn 2018. page 211.

> The main objection raised against the new model constructive trust was the fear that
> such an approach to proprietary entitlements would create uncertainty, and that decisions
> would depend on the personal moral feelings of the individual judge. This danger
> was clearly expressed by Bagnall J in Cowcher v Cowcher,150 where he considered the argument
> that injustice could result from the narrow criteria required for a constructive trust
> by the House of Lords in *Pettitt v Pettitt*151 and *Gissing v Gissing*:152
>
> > In any individual case the application of these propositions may produce a result which
> > appears unfair. So be it; in my view, that is not an injustice. I am convinced that in determining
> > rights, particularly property rights, the only justice that can be attained by mortals, who are
> > fallible and are not omniscient, is justice according to law; the justice which flows from the
> > application of sure and settled principles to proved or admitted facts. So in the field of equity
> > the length of the Chancellor’s foot has been measured or is capable of measurement. This
> > does not mean that equity is past the age of child bearing: simply that its progeny must be
> > legitimate—by precedent out of principle. It is ***well*** that this should be so; otherwise no lawyer
> > could safely advise on his client’s title and every quarrel would lead to a law suit.
>
> 150 [1972] 1 WLR 425 at 430. 151 [1970] AC 777. 152 [1971] AC 886.

Comment: The first is old-fashioned dialogue; the second is poetry; the third is formal legal language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*well* has a recognized adjective meaning as *better, best*:

[American Heritage Dictionary *well*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=well)

> adj. better, best
>
> 1. In a satisfactory condition; right or proper: *All is well*.
> 2. a. Not ailing, infirm, or diseased; healthy. See Synonyms at healthy.
>    b. Cured or healed, as a wound.
>    c. Of or characterized by the maintenance of good health practices. Often used in combination: *a well-baby clinic; a well-child visit to the doctor.*
> 3. a. Advisable; prudent: *It would be well not to ask.*
>    b. Fortunate; good: *It is well that you stayed.*

[Merriam-Webster *it is well that*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well)

> adj. 7 : being a cause for thankfulness : fortunate
> *it is well that this has happened*

Here is a Google ngram plot of **it is well that** over the years, with samples of the use at the bottom of the graph.

[Ngram *it is well that*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20is%20well%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20well%20that%3B%2Cc0)

It has a slightly old-fashioned ring to it in modern times, but other uses of *well* as an adjective are very common.

The name of a play by Shakespeare uses *well* both as an adjective and as an adverb:
*All's well that ends well*